# Python cannot initialize socket object

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am unable to initiate socket objects in Python.

```py
import socket
socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

And I get a traceback in the init function

```py
_socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

There seems to be very little information on what may be causing this. Any ideas on what the issue is here?

EDIT: I have fixed the caps in the question text as it was a typo. It was correct in my code editor however, and regardless, even this fails:

```py
import socket
socket.socket()
```

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This question's content and history make me doubtful. Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then copy&paste that code into your question. Do *not* type it.

Comment: No need to be snarky just because you can't reproduce. Question is as minimal as it can possibly be, and I've added a screenshot to curb your doubts about the content and history (lol what?)

Answer (score 1):

**CAPS MATTER!**

```
    socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Comment: See my edits - that was a typo in the question text, but my code had it correctly. And it still fails with socket.socket() without the args.